# What happens when I delete a pointer of pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have a vector like `std::vector<AnyObject*> myVector;` and I would like to delete an element in my vector without changing position of my other elements. How can I do this ? I have two solutions, tell me if they are good:

```
AnyObject* initial;
std::vector<AnyObject*> myVector(10, initial);
AnyObject* object = myVector.at(4);
delete object;
```

or

```
AnyObject* initial;
std::vector<AnyObject*> myVector(10, initial);
delete myVector.at(4);
```

What happens in the first solution when I delete `object` ? Am I also deleting the pointer in the vector or just the `object` ?

EDIT :

When I wrote `AnyObject* initial;`, I know `initial` isn't initialized, I wanted just say what happens if I a have a vector of initialized pointers and if I wanted delete one pointer without changing position of the other pointers.

EDIT2:

For the context of the problem, I have a class `PointCloud` and another class `SubsampledPointCloud`. I want subsampled my all clouds with the same size of the smallest cloud, so among my subsampled point cloud, I have at least one cloud that have the same size of its point cloud. So to build my vector of `SubsampledPointCloud`, I have a vector of `PointCloud` initialized, a variable `minPointCloudSize` equals to the minimum size among my point clouds and I do this :

```
std::vector<SubsampledPointCloud*> subcloud(clouds.size());
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < clouds.size(); i++) {
    if (clouds.at(i).size() > minPointCloudSize)
        subcloud.at(i) = subPointCloud(clouds.at(i)); //subPointCloud is a function 
                                                      //that return a SubsampledPointCloud*
    else
        subcloud.at(i) = clouds.at(i);
}
```

and later, I don't need of this subsampled point cloud, so I'm deleting all of this except if the sub cloud with the same size of the original cloud.
Of course, `SubsampledPointCloud` inherited of `PointCloud`.

Comment: you can do that but you are left with an invalid pointer in the vector I would  say, maybe not that good but not illegal either (obviously you should initialize `initial` as well as some programmer dude says).

Comment: Since you don't initialize `initial` then all elements in the vector will have the same *indeterminate* value, one that you can not `delete`. If you want to initialize the vector with ten null pointers, just let them be default initialized (by doing e.g. `std::vector<AnyObject*> myVector(10);`).

Comment: Oh and *if* you initialize `initial` then all ten elements will be pointing to the same memory, which means if you `delete` one then all the other pointers would become invalid.

Comment: Lastly, if you use pointers you have to remember that `delete` doesn't modify the actual pointer itself, so if you `delete` a pointer in the vector it will not be automatically set to `nullptr` but keep its (now invalid) value.

Comment: Sounds like a [XY-question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is it that you really want to achieve? Why do you use pointers at all instead of actual objects, if they are to die after usage anyway? For polymorphy? Can you give us some context, with some meaningful names like Car or Student? And why don't you use shared_ptr or unique_ptr?

Comment: @Aziuth, sorry my fault, I edited my post and I explained the context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have two solutions, tell me if they are good

Both of your solutions have UB - you read from uninitialized variable `initial`. If you manage to put correctly initialized pointers to your vector, then both variants would have the same effect - if fifth pointer in the vector not equal to `nullptr`, object it points to would be destroyed and memory released. You should understand that `delete` does not modify argument passed to it, so calling delete would not alter pointer itself and unless it is not equal to `nullptr` you would have dangling pointer left in the vector. It would be your job to reassign new value to it or to avoid using it after that. Or remove it from the vector calling vector methods.

> Am I also deleting the pointer in the vector or just the object ?

You are only deleting object, pointer would have exactly the same value ie point into memory where object used to be.

Answer (score 0):

A segmenation fault in both cases, as you haven't actually created any AnyObjects, only the vector of null pointers.

In general, if you have a vector of pointers to objects, you can delete the object by deleteing the object as you have done, and then setting the pointer to null, to denote that it doesn't point to an object.

To use your example, glossing over the fact you haven't created any objects:

```
AnyObject* initial;
std::vector<AnyObject*> myVector(10, initial);
delete myVector[4];
myVector[4] = 0;
```

Comment: "only the vector of null pointers." this is incorrect and if it would be true, deleting fifth element would be safe.

Comment: `initial` isn't `nullptr`.

Comment: Also, `delete nullptr` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @Gill Bates : Yes you are correct, its a vector of uninitialised pointers. I was being sloppy. My point was its unsafe to delete uninitialised pointers, which I alluded to with the segfault comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<AnyObject*> myVector(10, initial);
```

This statement will initialize vector with 10 `initial` object. `initial` is memory reference and when you `delete` it that deallocates memory that was allocated for `initial` object and will make all vector element pointing to invalid memory location in both case. If you will try to access it after delete in both case, the behavior will be undefined.

Comment: Yes, I didn't see this, but if the elements in the vector are all differents, what happens?

Comment: in that case it will have same impact i.e you are deleting object not the pointer. It will make that vector element point to invalid memory location.

Comment: if you delete one pointer i.e one element of vector it will have no impact on other elements if they are not pointing to same memory localtion

Answer (score 0):

Your premise is flawed. You shouldn't use raw pointers to handle object lifetimes, use `std::unique_ptr` (or `std::shared_ptr` if the lifetime *really is shared*)

Then your example would look like

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<AnyObject> > myVector(10, nullptr);
// other code
myVector[index] = make_unique<AnyObject>(args...);
// other code
myvector[other_index].reset(nullptr);
```